# PyTorch: How to distribute training work according to performance of each GPU?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

I've run into this problem of trying to train a neural network with two GPUs. One is Nvidia 1070 and the other one is Nvidia 2070. Obviously, 2070 is faster than 1070 and so if I just throw the same amount of training samples in each of them, 1070 would become the bottleneck which slows down the training process.

What I'm trying to do is to have these two GPUs do different amount of work. For example, if my batch size is 100, I'd like to have my 2070 card to deal with 80% of them and my 1070 card to deal with 20% of them. Is this possible with existing APIs that PyTorch provides? PyTorch's `DataParallel` and `DistributedDataParallel` don't seem to support this.

Comment: No, with the current implementation, it is not.

Comment: @Berriel Thanks for your info, sir. It is such a disappointing thing to realise :(